# How to identify levels of "plateaus" in a pandas series of float values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` that contains, amongst others, a series of time measurements (duration `n` of experiment `x` on sample `y`; in seconds).

In theory, every duration `n` is an integer multiple of the shortest duration within the series. Note that the shortest possible duration varies across different samples.

In reality, the time measurements are an approximation only. When sorting the duration according to length in seconds and plotting the result, I get something like this:

[image: Plotting of raw values]

**I want to open a new column and assign an integer to every measurement.  How to determine plateaus 1-3 in the figure above?**

I am interested in a scalable solution and hence can't divide by the smallest number in the series, since I will be facing thousands of samples in the future.

Comment: what have you tried? `pandas.Series.diff()` is probably a good way to identify relative plat sections of your data.

Comment: also, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
and then edit your question with your data and what you've tried

Comment: pandas.Series.diff() did the trick - many thanks!